# How to solve NA values for standard errors, z and pr values when we are calculation ARIMA model in R? In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, quantmod, arima, quantitative-finance, forecast

I have been doing future forecasting using ARIMA model in R programming language but when I run ARIMA model from the forecast package, my standard errors are not calculated properly and got an `NA` error.
Could you please advise me in order to solve this issue?

arima(5,1,5)

```
arima515 <- Arima(GSPC$SP500, 
                  order = c(5, 1, 5), 
                  include.constant = TRUE,
                  optim.control = list(maxit = 500),)

coeftest(arima515)
```

Output:

```
z test of coefficients:

       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
ar1    0.074793         NA      NA       NA   
ar2    0.142322         NA      NA       NA   
ar3    0.754132         NA      NA       NA   
ar4    0.179091         NA      NA       NA   
ar5   -0.370530         NA      NA       NA   
ma1   -0.122067         NA      NA       NA   
ma2   -0.180075         NA      NA       NA   
ma3   -0.751949         NA      NA       NA   
ma4   -0.147119         NA      NA       NA   
ma5    0.381992         NA      NA       NA   
drift  0.387899   0.132093  2.9366 0.003319 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(se)) : NaNs produced
```

As you can see above that errors, `z` values and `pr` are `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly the question, but if you want only parameter standard errors you could only call `arima515`or `summary(arima515)`, like this

```
arima515 <- Arima(cop[,1], 
                  order = c(5, 1, 5), 
                  include.constant = TRUE,
                  optim.control = list(maxit = 500))

summary(arima515)

Series: cop[, 1] 
ARIMA(5,1,5) with drift 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4     ar5      ma1     ma2      ma3
      -0.7413  -1.2671  -0.5753  -0.3700  0.0221  -0.2412  0.5399  -0.7129
s.e.   1.4269   0.6982   1.1093   0.5289  0.0852   1.4266  1.1724   0.8139
          ma4      ma5   drift
      -0.1744  -0.4114  -1e-04
s.e.   1.0093   0.5184   1e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.5005:  log likelihood=-801.31
AIC=1626.63   AICc=1627.05   BIC=1682.05

Training set error measures:
                       ME      RMSE      MAE  MPE MAPE      MASE
Training set -0.005256166 0.7017616 0.513783 -Inf  Inf 0.6721109
                      ACF1
Training set -0.0009624799
```

you will get parameter estimates and s.e. See the documentation for `coeftest` and see which object you can use for this function. Instead if you wanted to test anything else for your *Arima* model tell us what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, I want to see the calculation of standard errors instead of NA values. Because when I run the above code. I receive NA instead of numbers. I am investigating how to solve this problem

Comment: I just follow up your method and run the summary, and still have the same NA errors for some of the lags. please see below:' > summary(arima515)
  ar1     ar2     ar3     ar4      ar5      ma1      ma2      ma3      ma4     ma5   drift
      0.0054  0.2694  0.6245  0.2326  -0.5186  -0.0499  -0.3091  -0.6215  -0.2074  0.5197  0.3791
s.e.     NaN  0.0936  0.0742     NaN   0.1114      NaN      NaN   0.0727      NaN  0.1022  0.1380
AIC=61338.78   AICc=61338.82   BIC=61421.94 Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced' 
There is even and warning  ' NaNs produced '

Comment: is there something wrong with your time series? you analyzed it?

Comment: I don’t think so, because i am using S&P500 time series from yahoo finance.